# How to access children of children recursively?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a Canvas which has many components inside it and those again, have many components inside them.

getChildren() returns only the top level children. What is the best way to retrieve all the children (children of children of children and so on).

Well, I sorta know how to do this by iterating through the children, but the code is really messy. I'd prefer to use a nice recursive function. Has anyone written this before? Or is there a Util class to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private function recuse(display : DisplayObjectContainer) : void {
  if(display) {
    for (var i : int = 0;i < _display.numChildren;i++) {
        var child : DisplayObject = display.getChildAt(i);
        trace(child.name);
        if(child is DisplayObjectContainer) {
            recuse(DisplayObjectContainer(child));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That is pretty much the same solution isn't it ?

Comment: This works smoothly, thanks! Correction: _display should be display

Comment: theo: yes, it seems quite similar, i didn't see your solution when i posted mine. so it seems a bit unfair that i got the check...

Answer (score 3):

Try something likely (note you can return the lists recursively if you want to gather all the references to the top level iteration)

```
function inspect(object:DisplayObject):void
{
    if(object is DisplayObjectContainer)
    {
        var casted:DisplayObjectContainer = object as DisplayObjectContainer

        trace("DisplayObjectContainer ", casted.name)

        for(var depth:int = 0; depth < casted.numChildren;depth++)
        {
            inspect(casted.getChildAt(depth))
        }

    }else{

        trace("DisplayObject", object.name );
    }
}


inspect(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function theCallbackFunction(obj:DisplayObject):void
{
  trace(obj.name);
}

//Visit the children first.
//Deep most objects will be visited first and so on.
//stage is visited at the end.
//Uses recursion
function depthFirst(obj:DisplayObject, func:Function):void
{
  if(!(obj instanceof DisplayObjectContainer))
  {
    func(obj);
    return;
  }
  var p:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(obj);
  var len:Number = p.numChildren;
  for(var i:Number = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    var child:DisplayObject = p.getChildAt(i);
    depthFirst(child, func);
  }
  func(obj);
}   

//Visit the siblings first.
//stage is visited first, then its children, then the grand children and so on
//No recursion.
function breadthFirst(obj:DisplayObject, func:Function):void
{
  var q:Array = []; 
  q.push(obj);
  var p:DisplayObjectContainer;
  var i:Number, len:Number;
  while(q.length != 0) 
  {     
    var child:DisplayObject = queue.shift();
    func(child);
    if(!(child instanceof DisplayObjectContainer))
      continue;         
    p = DisplayObjectContainer(child);
    len = p.numChildren;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) 
      q.push(p.getChildAt(i));
  }     
}

depthFirst(this.stage, theCallbackFunction);
breadthFirst(this.stage, theCallbackFunction);
```