# Disable mouse wheel scroll on child component

Tags: apache-flex, air

here is the layout:

```
<s:Scroller>
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:List id="list1"/>
        <s:List id="list2"/>
        <component:ThirdPartyComponent/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

so, my application should only showing 1 scroll to the right which is the scoller, list1, list2 etc should not showing scroll.

it was working fine for a moment until we found that mouse wheel scroll not working. seem the `mouseWheel` event captured by the child component (list and thirdparty).

searched through the net to find solution, there is solution to `stopImmediatePropagation()` of the child `mouseWheel` event, but seems it is not a good solution. beside the part of ThirdPartyCompoent that doing scroll is a private member, so no way to listen `mouseWheel` from ThirdPartyCompoent

any idea?

### CASE CLOSE

so far, the case solved by listen the `mouseWheel` event and disable root `VGroup mouseChildren` there, then on the root `VGroup` click handler i enable the `mouseChildren`. **but if there is more elegan solution please comment.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these options could help you

**OPTION#: 1**

```
<component:ThirdPartyComponent 
           creationComplete = "afterCreation()" 
           id               = "TPComponent">
  <fx:Script>

     // You could use initialize or creationComplete to handle MouseWheel Listener
     private function afterCreation():void{
       this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, hoverHandler);
     }
     private function hoverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
       if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.cancelBubble = true;
         e.cancel = true;
         e.returnValue = false;
       }
       return false;
     }
  </fx:Script>
</component:ThirdPartyComponent>
```

But I suggest you to disable MouseWheel in children components with MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, because it covers all area of any child object of the display object container. The buble event should return to false so that the children would have no chance to dispatch any mouse event including the MOUSE_WHEEL.

**OPTION#: 2**

```
<component:ThirdPartyComponent 
           creationComplete = "afterCreation()" 
           id               = "TPComponent">
  <fx:Script>

     private function afterCreation():void{
       this.mouseChildren = false;
     }

  </fx:Script>
</component:ThirdPartyComponent>
```

By setting mouseChildren to false, events on any mouseChildren are given to the parent magically. mouseChildren is not equal to mouseEnabled, so any given return of it will give different impact :)

You could combine Option# 1 & Option# 2 or choose one of them, which is the best for you :)

Comment: thank you very much @JackBites, do you mean inherit the thirdparty component (by creating a new single mxml component)?

Comment: for option2, i can't set the `mouseChildren = false` because the ThirdPartyComponent (a calendar) has children which is should clickable.

Comment: you not need to inherit thirdparty component to single mxml file you could just add fx:Script inside of ThirdPartyComponent as a member of VGroup.

Comment: for option 2: you could add mouseChildren control based on spesific events only, example if MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, set mouseChildren to false. and release it for another mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

you can access third party components children via recursion

[How to access children of children recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416553/how-to-access-children-of-children-recursively)

and add mouse wheel block handler to children you need

Comment: thanks for the help, but this is not help, the child component is not accessible via `getChildAt` and `getChildByName` :(